# TexStudio problem (Error: Could not start the command)

Tags: errors

I have a problem for texstudio software. When I write a very basic format, it always goes wrong. The error presents as "Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "First year Ro.".tex".

How to fix it? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a TeX distribution installed?

Comment: perhaps not, I am a beginner of Texstudio, would you mind telling me how to download it? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the Miktex?

Comment: Miktex or texlive or mactex if you are using a Mac. TeXStudio is just a front end, it does not provide LaTeX the "program"

Comment: it works well, thanks!!